# String Grouping Based On Name

Tags: python, string, string-parsing

I am trying to learn some python coding on my own and I came through this problem::

Input Text File Contents::

```
10280341|2012-10-03 19:11:06.390|Sami|abc|Crossword|70
10280343|2012-10-03 19:15:32.173|Sami|aaa|Sudoku|30
10280355|2012-10-04 19:18:32.173|miami|bbb|Chaircar|15
10280366|2012-10-04 19:19:32.173|miami|bob|Avista|35
```

Output Expected::

```
2012-10-03 Sami|2|100
2012-10-04 miami|2|50
```

I know this can be done through String Parsing & Matching but I do not have any idea, where to start. Any links or pointers would be highly helpful to any similar problem.
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools.groupby` as has already been suggested, or make use of the `csv.reader` object which is already a generator and a `collections.defaultdict` to aggregate the value column...

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

summary = defaultdict(list)
csvin = csv.reader(open('testdata.txt'), delimiter='|')
for row in csvin:
    summary[(row[1].split(' ')[0], row[2])].append(int(row[5]))

csvout = csv.writer(open('testdata.out','wb'), delimiter='|')
for who, what in summary.iteritems():
    csvout.writerow( [' '.join(who), len(what), sum(what)] )
```

If you're looking at more complicated cross tabulation/pivoting etc..., then it may well be worth having a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which is a very useful library based on `numpy`

Comment: Hey thanks a lot it worked but my file is an unicode file. It returns a null byte after parsing the first char. Any suggestions.

Comment: No suppose there is one more line  
  **10280343|2012-10-05 19:15:32.173|Sami|aaa|Sudoku|30**  
It should group by date 
eg:-  
  **2012-10-03 Sami|2|100**  
  **2012-10-04 miami|2|50**
  **2012-10-05 Sami|1|30**

Answer (score 1):

Use [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to read the file. Use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the rows after sorting them. Use [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) to sum up each of the values in the grouped rows, via a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).